# Having 2 @media print in 1 css file

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is that possible to have 2 @media print in 1 css file? I used @media print{ ... } twice in my css file but it did not work. Besides, it is not working on IE, Opera and Chrome properly. Even it does not work in firefox 100% correctly.

here is my code:

```css
 @media print {
   #sidebar {
     display: none;
     position: static;
   }
   #content {
     left: 0;
   }
   #daily-overview-grid-wrapper,
   .daily-overview-navigator-bar {
     display: none;
   }
   #daily-overview-content-wrapper {
     left: 0;
     border-left: none;
   }
   .daily-overview-content-header,
   #content > div > header,
   .daily-overview-detail-item-header {
     border-bottom: solid 1px #888 !important;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want two?

Comment: my css file is rather big and I want to have related codes together. So I sometime need to use media query several times but I'm not sure if it's correct or best practice.